# How do I see what I am currently subscribed to?

Tags: steam

In the Steam workshop, how do I see the list of items that I'm currently subscribed to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using Firefox for the below screenshots, but it looks the same in Steam's browser/view, too. First go to your "Community" page and find the "View Workshop files" link on the right side:

[image]

Then on the workshop files page, click the "Subscribed Items" tab on the right side:

[image]

You should also be able to get to it by using the "Workshop" link at the top of the page and then finding the "Your workshop files" link towards the right side of that page (it should have your avatar next to it).

Comment: They have changed things since this answer was posted.  The other answer still works, though.

Comment: Go to your profile. Scroll down the right-hand bit until you find Workshop Items.  On Workshop Items you'll see Subscriptions.

Comment: Where is the 'community page'?

Answer (score 11):

how to: through steam client window

[image: step1]

then this picture

[image: step2]