# Portal 2 re-downloads deleted community maps

Tags: portal-2

When I try delete the files directly from the workshop folder on my computer, they are downloaded again when I start up Portal 2? How do I delete them permanently? They are taking up 5GB of space!

Comment: Have you returned to the workshop pages for the maps and *unsubscribed* from them?

Comment: Note:  [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/211465/87105) tells you how to get the list of everything you're subscribed to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use the answer found on a steam community form found [HERE](http://steamcommunity.com/app/550/discussions/0/864975399737522530/)

> First, unsubscribe from the addon. It'll keep Steam from
>   re-downloading the mod every time you start the game.
>
> Then you'll want to follow this file path: **`[Drive you have Steam
>   installed on] > Program Files or Program Files (x86)* > Steam >
>   steamapps > common > left 4 dead 2 > left4dead2 > addons >
>   workshop`**.
>
> Most mods are packaged in a file with a .vpk suffix. Find the .vpk
>   file you want to remove, delete it, and voila. It's gone. This last
>   step may be a bit hard if you have multiple Workshop mods as Workshop
>   mods are numerically named.
>
> Side Note: The addons folder where the workshop folder is located is
>   where you paste .vpk addons you download manually to install them.
>
> *Steam should be in Program Files if you have a 32-bit OS, or Program Files (x86) if you have a 64-bit OS. If it's not in one, check the
>   other.

===========================================================================

If that doesn't work [HERE](https://steamcommunity.com/app/620/discussions/0/619574421458539874/) is another solution to remove workshop items:

open a shell and go to maps/workshop then type

```
dir /S/O/B *.bsp >doit.bat
dir /S/O/B *.jpg >>doit.bat
notepad doit.bat
find and replace .bsp to .bsp"
find and replace .jpg to .jpg"
find and replace C: to copy null "C:
save and exit notepad
generate a file with no content named null
start doit.bat
```

all jpg and bsp files are changed to zero filesize

Comment: I'm not talking about items I subscribed to in the workshop.  When I play the "top rated" levels they download and I can't get rid of them.

Comment: I would treat them like regular workshop items. Anyway when you want to play them I'm pretty sure it automatically subscribes you to them so the map can downlaod